# System Health OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues. We recommend using the Oracle JRE/JDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

В чем разница между Open JDK и Oracle JDK?

Я так понял они делают одно и тоже... Просто я работал с OpenCV и пока разбирался как установить эту библиотеку наверное нечайно установил и OpenJDK и теперь студия показывает мне такое сообщение :

```
"System Health
OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues. We recommend using the Oracle JRE/JDK."
```

И я вот думаю нужно теперь обратно все переустанавливать?