# В чем разница между Open JDK и Oracle JDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

В чем разница между Open JDK и Oracle JDK?

Я так понял они делают одно и тоже... Просто я работал с OpenCV и пока разбирался как установить эту библиотеку наверное нечайно установил и OpenJDK и теперь студия показывает мне такое сообщение :

```
Что рекомендуется использовать  Oracle JDK
```

И я вот думаю нужно теперь обратно все переустанавливать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [System Health OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues. We recommend using the Oracle JRE/JDK](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502747/system-health-openjdk-shows-intermittent-performance-and-ui-issues-we-recommend)

Comment: [Как раз про это есть инфа в ответе KoVadim](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502767/202778)

Comment: Алексей, зачем вы один и тот же вопрос дважды задали?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

разница между ними очень простая - одно выпускает Оракл и является "правильной, оригинальной JVM" от производителя. OpenJDK - это альтернативная разработка, открытая (в отличии от оракловской реализации) - можно посмотреть исходники.

И хотя между ними в теории не должно быть отличий, всеже они есть. Самое главное - это лицензия. Все остальное мелочи. Но вот только эти мелочи иногда и вылазят.

Android Studio построена на базе IDEA от JetBrains, а следовательно содержит все те же особенности. Разработчики IDEA глубоко ковыряются в JVM и видимо используют какие то особенности, что в результате на OpenJDK начинает иногда хромать графика (например, плохо отрисовываются шрифты). Поэтому они рекомендуют использовать jdk от Оракла.

**как пофиксить минимальными усилиями?**

Самый простой и красивый способ - это задать переменную окружения `JDK_HOME` (или `STUDIO_JDK` - если хотите исключительно для студии) равной папке, где храниться jdk (проверить это просто - в этой папке должна быть папка `bin`, в которой будет `java`). Это работает под всеми осями. Более того, вы можете даже скачать себе отдельно и распаковать и прописать.

Comment: Я не сильно опытный пользователь Ubuntu. Вы имеете ввиду, что нужно прописать путь к папке jdk (путь я могу прописать в файле который могу открыть с помощью этой команды sudo nano /etc/environment) , но когда я открываю usr/lib/jdk чтоб посмотреть какие файлы там есть то там нет файлов oracle только openJDK. Если я правильно понял то мне нужно найти где у меня храниться оригинальная JDK и в том файле прописать пути к ней? Так?

Comment: не надо туда лазить. Используйте ~/.bash_profile или аналоги и выставляйте для **локального пользователя**.

Comment: Ок... Но пока я чинил проблему с jdk я уже залез туда и дописал строчку как сказано в этом примере http://goo.gl/KQ6tkf  ))

Comment: А как задать переменную окружения?

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` этого будет достаточно. См. [Как установить Java в Ubuntu с помощью Apt-Get](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-ubuntu-apt-get-ru)

Comment: update-alternatives выставляет для всей системы, а это может быть лишним.

Как поправить переменную окружения.
`vim ~/.bashrc`, после запуска shift+g, o. вводим текст " export JAVA_HOME=/тут путь", `Esc :w`. Потом лучше перелогиниться.

Comment: А может быть не надо торопиться? Седьмая версия Android SDK построена на OpenJDK, придётся назад всё перенастраивать.

Comment: @KoVadim, если есть опасения в установке JDK для всей системы, хотя я сильно сомневаюсь, что это может что-то повредить (это ж не боевой сервер же какой-то), то правильнее прописать всё что надо прямо в файле .jdk непосредственно для этой версии IDEA см. [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

Comment: может ли это навредить? может. У меня был опыт, когда нужно было работать с клиентом для банка, который использовал java и софтиной от cisco. И они хотели свои версии java. И обе запускались очень "хитро". Я долго настраивал систему, что бы их разрулить. В конце концов появился отдельно установленный фаерфокс, для которого был написан специальный bash файл.

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы писали: "OpenJDK - это альтернативная разработка, открытая (в отличии от оракловской реализации) - можно посмотреть исходники". А разве у Oracle JDK нельзя посмотреть исходники? Или их можно увидеть только с помощью декомпиляции?..

Comment: Я не видел, где все исходники можно забрать. Но, зная Оракл, сделать с этими исходниками что то вряд ли получится. То есть, скопировал себе несколько методов и все... плати (собственно на эту тему и был у них  суд с гуглом/андроидом)

Comment: Пара вопросов. В `JDK_HOME` надо указать путь до OpenJDK или скачать Oracle и установить его в переменную специально для IDEA? И как оно работает, за этой переменной сама IDEA следит? Почему не достаточно `JAVA_HOME`, которая в себе по сути тоже содержит путь до JDK?

Comment: этот коментарий прям сам говорит, что нужно с него сделать "пару вопросов".